# SDL doesn't know Iphone audio device?

Tags: iphone, sdl, core-audio

Thanks for reading my question.
I used SDL for the purpose of video streaming Iphone App.

I initialize the SDL like this.

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
}
```

But I always got the same error message.

```
Could not initialize SDL - No available audio device
```

I used SDL-1.3.0-5605.
It seems that SDL couldn't recognize Iphone audio device.
What I should do? In order to SDL can recognize Iphone audio device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is used old define in include/SDL_config_iphoneos.h

Rewrite

```
#define SDL_AUDIO_DRIVER_COREAUDIOIPHONE 1
```

to

```
#define SDL_AUDIO_DRIVER_COREAUDIO 1
```

For me works it well.